# Creating a function to see increase or decrease in column value per group of unique ids

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that tracks the customer journey:

```
id| event_name| event_date

1| entered|2019-07

1| purchase = 2|2019-07

1| purchase = 2|2019-07

2| entered|2019-07

2| purchase = 0|2019-07

2| purchase = 2|2019-07
```

I want to understand for each unique customer ID, has the purchased items increased or decreased.

I created a new df with only purchase related events and a new column in the dataframe by parsing out the event name and only having purchases.

```
id| event_name| event_date| num_of_purchase

1| purchase = 2|2019-07|2

1| purchase = 2|2019-07|2

2| purchase = 0|2019-07|0

2| purchase = 2|2019-07|2
```

I created a function that shows me if there was a change in the number of purchases and applied it to my original df. However, I want to know if the purchases for that unique customer increased or decreased.

```
def num_purchase(x):
    if x['num_of_purchase'].nunique() == 1:
        x['change_in_purchase'] = 0
    else:
        x['change_in_purchase'] = 1
    return x
```

I thought if I used .unique, I can use the array results and have a variable to see if it increases or decreases. I just dont know how to write this.

I essentially want another column to show whether this customers purchases increased, decreased or stayed the same. So the table would look like:

```
id| event_name| event_date| num_of_purchase| change_in purchase

1| purchase = 2|2019-07|2|same

1| purchase = 2|2019-07|2|same

2| purchase = 0|2019-07|0|increase

2| purchase = 2|2019-07|2|increase
```

Bonus: would it be possible to also get the exact number of change. For example, for customer 2 it went from 0 -2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
df['change_in purchase'] = df.groupby('id')['num_of_purchase']\
                             .transform(lambda x: (str(x.iloc[0]) + 
                                                   ' to ' + 
                                                   str(x.iloc[-1]) if x.iloc[0] != x.iloc[-1] 
                                                   else 'same'))
```

Output:

```
   id     event_name event_date  num_of_purchase change_in purchase
0   1   purchase = 2    2019-07                2               same
1   1   purchase = 2    2019-07                2               same
2   2   purchase = 0    2019-07                0             0 to 2
3   2   purchase = 2    2019-07                2             0 to 2
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to make it that that if the number increases or decreases it is just increase or decrease. And then if it did increase or decrease have the net difference be an integer so + 2 or -2